# Multiplicação recursiva em C

Tags: c

Estou aprendendo recursividade em C, e consegui fazer alguns programinhas usando a recursividade. Entretanto, estou apanhando para fazer um simples programa que o usuário mandando dois números, exemplo: 6x2, eu os multiplico em recursão. Posso até mostrar o código abaixo, mas tenho certeza que ele foge totalmente da realidade do real código.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int poligono(int n,int v){
    int res=0;

    if(v==0)
        return 0;
    else if(n==0)
        return n;
    else
        return n + poligono(n,v);
}

int main(){

    int n,v,res=0;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&v);
    res=poligono(n,v);
    printf("Res = %d\n",res);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: que tal utilizar main como deve ser utilizado para ver se compila? Use: int main() { /*seu código...*/ return 0; }

Comment: Para perceberes o que está mal, pega em 2 números quaisquer e faz a recursividade à mão num papel. Vais conseguir ver o teu problema.

Comment: Fora que teu código gera uma recursividade infinita, logo seu código gera um erro chamado (acho que você já ouviu falar, rsrs) Stack Overflow. Pois excede o limite de chamadas "empilhadas" na pilha (stack).

Comment: Bruno, peço-lhe desculpas, pois o código que não compilava era outro. Esse compila. Logo vou editar minha pergunta.

Comment: @Fiodor faz o que eu te disse, pega em 2 números e percorre a função recursivamente, mas vai escrevendo no papel e vais entender onde está o teu problema.

Comment: Seguirei seu conselho, @JorgeB.

Comment: @Fiodor eu reverti a sua pergunta, para que as respostas que já tinha não ficarem invalidas. avisei o Math também para editar a resposta dele.

Answer (score 2):

Alguns pontos a melhorar:

1. A verificação no primeiro if é desnecessária, você precisa tratar o `n` que é o número de vezes que o seu código é iterado, nunca o `v`, que deve ser um valor fixo a ser somado com ele mesmo por `n` vezes.
2. Nunca se deve retornar `n`, somente `v`.
3. O valor de `n` deve ser decrementado a cada iteração, ou incrementado, caso `n` seja um valor negativo.
4. No seu algoritmo não são tratados os valores negativos.

Juntando tudo isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int poligono(int n, int v){
    int vs;
    if(n>0){
        n--;
        vs = v;
    }
    else if (n<0){
        n++;
        vs = -v;
    }

    if(n==0)
        return vs;
    else
        return vs + poligono(n,v);
}

int main(){

    int n,v,res=0;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&v);
    res=poligono(n,v);
    printf("Res = %d\n",res);

    return 0;

}
```

Veja um exemplo no Ideone: https://ideone.com/XjxKnG

Comment: originalmente não havia o "n - 1", ele editou a pergunta após meu comentário acima,,,

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado. Entretanto, só fui ter consciência de que tinha de ter um decremento ali devido aos usuários acima.

Comment: @JoséX. ah tah, não acompanhei todo o histórico da evolução da pergunta, mas foi um ponto importante a se corrigir.

Comment: Math eu reverti a pergunta, para não ser camaleônica, se quiseres editar a resposta...

Comment: @JorgeB. agora que vi o histórico da edição, tem bastante coisa lá hein? rs..

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, uma questão que tem que ser obedecida na recursividade é que ela seja finita, ou seja, tem que existir uma saída do seu programa. Se você quer fazer uma multiplicação recursiva, faria desse jeito:

```
int poligono( int a, int b ){

   if( b == 1)
     return a;
   return a + poligono(a, --b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Um algoritmo recursivo sempre pressupõe a utilização do mesmo algoritmo em um problema mais simples, até que eventualmente o problema é tão simples que não é mais necessário usar recursividade.

No seu exemplo, a linha
   `return n + poligono(n,v);`
deveria ser
   `return n + poligono(n-1,v);`

Note que nem estou analisando se seu programa funciona corretamente, estou apenas resolvendo o problema da recursividade infinita.

(Estou também assumindo que eventualmente você colocará alguma consistência para evitar o uso de valores negativos.)

Comment: Não entendi a sua primeira frase, quer dizer que o algoritmo recursivo nunca deveria existir em produção?

Comment: @Math "problema mais simples" na verdade deveria ser "sub-problema mais simples"; no caso em questão é quando n == 0; concordo que o texto não está muito claro, escrevi apressadamente e depois não quis editar

Comment: Ah tah, agora entendi. Bom, se editasse poderia deixar a resposta mais completa, de qlq forma ai vai meu +1

Answer (score 0):

O método recursivo para a multiplicação de dois fatores é 3+3+3+3=11:
primeiro pense em como é feita a multiplicação.
3*4=11 é o mesmo que 3 + 4*2 que significa o mesmo que 3 + (4*(3-1)) recursivamente

```
int poligono(int a , int b) {
        if ((a == 0)||(b==0))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return a + poligono(b,(a-1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: 3+4*2 dá 11, e não 12